# Square API callbacks on successfull checkout payment

Tags: security, payment, square

I am using the Square API to process user payment (using the `Create Checkout Link` API):  `POST /v2/online-checkout/payment-links`.

The problem is that square does not support out-of-the-box callback functions on payment success and payment failure, it only provides a `redirect_url` option to send the user to another page when they finish the payment.

The way I solved it now is to generate a random `secret key` for each `purchase intent` and pass the key as an argument in the `redirect_url`:

```
redirectr_url = "https://example.com?pid=5&secret_key=abcdefgh12345"
```

This however exposes the inner-workings of my system to anyone remotely skilled in IT, they can see that I pass a secret key as a `GET` argument.

Even though the secret key is a variation with class `25` and number of elements `64` where order of elements is important and repetition is allowed (which works out to `~2*10^84`, if there is ever a leak of the database (e.g. hosting provider is compromised), all the secret keys will be up for grabs and people can just manually hit the API to approve their purchases. I need to either make this more subtle or change the payment validation process altogether.

Any way I can improve my current system? Is there a way to somehow use Square's API to verify a purchase success via callback like the Stripe API provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your key to the `redirect_url` but as you pointed out that's easily accessible to bad actors.  Have you looked at added your secret key as a `reference_id` in the payment link order? Once the payment is complete you can take the `order_id` and call [RetrieveOrder](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/retrieve-order) to get all order details including your unique `reference_id` which wouldn't be accessible to bad actors.

Comment: I unfortunately abandoned the effort shortly after I discovered that accepting payments in Macedonia is not yet supported.
If I recall correctly, I used reference_id for something else, but I suppose I could have separated the secret key and the ID I stored in reference_id with a special character of some sort. 
Thanks for the help, your answer seems like a solution that could help someone in the future so I will approve it. 
If you work at Square and have any say in the matter, could you please look into expending your support for more countries as I found your API very good? Thanks.